# Run Matlab commands with reduced priority

Tags: matlab, configuration, thread-priority

I frequently encounter the following problem: I start a time-consuming (sometimes parallelized) script, and while the said script is running Matlab becomes very slow & unresponsive. (I would like to keep editing files). I suspect that part of the problem is that the script that's running is eating up all CPU capacities.

Hence my question: is there a way to start all commands from within Matlab with a reduced process priority, while not reducing the priority of the Matlab GUI from which these processes are started? I'd be interested in solutions for Windows & Linux.

E.g., on Linux I know I can increase the niceness of the sub-processes using `renice` on the command line, but I obviously do not want to do so manually each time. I also checked whether there's a way to start the parallel worker threads with a modified priority, but I could not find anything in the documentation. Ideally - as in many other IDEs - there would be a setting somewhere in Matlab where one can configure how to run commands, and I would change it from `matlab ...` to `nice -10 matlab ...`.

Comment: Perhaps limiting the [number of computational threads](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html) can help

Comment: What have you tried? This doesn't sound like a programming question and it might be better suited to Super User instead of Stack Overflow

Comment: Just open a second MATLAB instance? call matlab from command line, with no GUI, and let that run on a window, then do whatever you want

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is probably the most convenient solution. I was hoping for some way to configure this within Matlab, but maybe that does not exist?

Comment: I don't know, I always just do that.

Comment: I do the same than @AnderBiguri, don't know yet of any more convenient method.